# SWFLoader loading subapp that access it own resource

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm having the following problem when I'm loading a swf inside a swfloader. That thing is that this subapp has a config file, and when this config file is being accessed by the subapp it throws an Security error (#2148).

I thought it was the crossdomain.xml file, but it has no reestrictions:

I suppose that the subapp is trying to access a config file that is in the swf parent server insted of trying to access its own file in the server where it is installed;

Somebody knows how to make this swfloader access its own data, or some way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you loading the config file with an absolute path? If you use a relative path from the subapp, it will search the parent swf's filesystem for the config file, rather than where you originally stored it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you think the file should be, and the code snippet you're using to access the config file. It would be useful to have examples from both parent and subapp.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved. !!

Lookslike I needed to test on the server, not on my local folder.

For this, I changed the flash builder "**output folder**" in "**flex build path**" project properties to throw the compilation resources to my server folder.

aditionaly to help in the debugging I created a new run configuration where the path to launch where the swf in my server folder.

Thanks for the people that helped me a little. Thanks  :)